# Total cost and public cost of sports stadiums

Tags: data-request, sports

I'm interested in doing data analysis on the cost of large sports stadiums (in the US). I have an excellent data source in "Financing Professional Sports Facilities" (Robert A. Baade, Victor Matheson) but it only goes up to 2011. The scholarly literature on this is vast, but I'm wondering if anyone's done any comparable tabulating for the period after 2011?

Answer (score 0):

I've since found a couple of Wikipedia pages that seem to address this question.

https://cbsminnesota.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/nfl-funding-summary-12-2-11.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_expensive_stadiums

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stadium_subsidy#:~:text=Stadium%20subsidies%20can%20come%20in,controversial%20among%20legislators%20and%20citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stadium_subsidy#:%7E:text=Stadium%20subsidies%20can%20come%20in,controversial%20among%20legislators%20and%20citizens).